# I am adding classes to a Foxes and Rabbit simulation called Fox and Owl and I am having an issue in the Owl class

Tags: java, class, simulation, bluej

My owl class is very identical to my fox class, it is actually copied exactly word for word except new birthing probabilities and unique things i added to the Owl, but my problem is i have a Randomizer class to produce random numbers for birthing probabilites, etc. This is the variable

// A shared random number generator to control breeding.
    private static final Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();

Now i'm coding in BlueJ because seeing the class diagram helps and i'm getting the error message cannot find Symbol - class Random.

I don't understand why this is a problem because it works perfectly in the Fox class and they all point to the same objects.

Comment: Then you need to import `Random`I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press while you code in your owl class the buttons `STRG + SHIFT + O` to import `java.util.Random` to your class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `import java.util.Random` at the top of both classes.